# SugarCRM Enterprise 6.5 - "app is not defined"

Tags: javascript, sugarcrm

I'm trying to dynamically display a button in the detail view of a given record, depending on its record and the role of the current user. In order to do so, I'm including a custom javascript file in a detail view definition file, in *custom/modules/Tasks/metadata/hide.js*.

I need to access to the roles of a user, so first I'm trying to access to the user object. However, this fails:

`var user = app.data.createBean('Users', {id: app.user.id});`

It throws the following error: `ReferenceError: app is not defined`.

What's the right way to get the user (and then the role) through javascript in SugarCRM Enterprise 6.5?

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using will work only with sugarcrm 7 or later versions.
App variable is not available in sugar 6.5.

You need to write custom api to get user roles.
In php you can get roles like this

```
global $current_user;
include_once('modules/ACLRoles/ACLRole.php');
$roles = getUserRoleNames($current_user->id);
print_r($roles);
```